# How to set up paging on Fuelux

Tags: javascript, fuelux

I'm try to use FUELUX reperater, and I have all the data working fine.
Now, my question is:

How can I set up properly the paging? cause at the moment it displays all the results in one single page and I have a maximum call stack exceeded error in the console.

This is the code that I have:

```
  function getCheckinData(options, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "../wp-content/plugins/hg-reports/includes/checkin_page/JSON_data.php",
            data: {
                filter: options.filter.value,
                search: (typeof options.search != 'undefined') ? options.search : "",
                sort_property: (typeof options.sortProperty != 'undefined') ? options.sortProperty : "",
                sort_direction: (typeof options.sortDirection != 'undefined') ? options.sortDirection : ""
            }
        })
            .done(function (data, result, jqXHR) {
                var checkinData = JSON.parse(data).data;

                _.templateSettings.variable = "badNode";
                var template = _.template(
                    $("script.template").html()
                );

                _.each(checkinData, function (row) {
                    row.badNodesHTML = "";
                    var HG_action_login = '<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" target="_blank" href="#"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i> APP</a>';

                    row.HG_actions = HG_action_login;
                    if (row.badNodes.length) {
                        _.each(row.badNodes, function (badNode) {
                            [badNode.address].toString()
                            badNode.address = /:(.+)/.exec(badNode.address)[1];
                            row.badNodesHTML += template(badNode);
                            row.HG_actions;
                        });
                    }
                });


                var resp = {
                    columns: [
                        {label: "Actions", property: "HG_actions", sortable: false, className: "actions", width: 70},
                        {label: "User", property: "customer", sortable: true, width: 200, className: "userCell"},
                        {label: "Description", property: "description", sortable: false, width: 180, className: "editableDescription"},
                        {label: "Flag", property: "flag", sortable: false, width: 60, className: "editableFlag"},
                        {label: "Build", property: "build", sortable: false, width: 150},
                        //    {label: "TimeStamp", property: "ts", sortable: true, width: 180},
                        {label: "Checkin", property: "checkin", sortable: true, width: 250},
                        {label: "MAC", property: "site", sortable: true, width: 200, className: "macAddressColumn"},
                        // {label: "Address", property: "address", sortable: false, width: 150},
                        {label: "Boiler", property: "boiler", sortable: false, width: 150},
                        {label: "Nodes", property: "nodes", sortable: false, width: 80},
                        {label: "BadNodes", property: "badNodesHTML", sortable: false, className: "badNodes"}
                    ],
                    count: checkinData.length,
                    items: checkinData,
                    page: options.pageIndex,
                    pages: Math.ceil(checkinData.length / (options.pageSize || 50))
                };

                var items = checkinData;

                var pageIndex = options.pageIndex;
                var pageSize = options.pageSize;
                var data = items;

                var totalItems = data.length;
                var totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);
                var startIndex = (pageIndex * pageSize) + 1;
                var endIndex = (startIndex + pageSize) - 1;
                if (endIndex > data.length) {
                    endIndex = data.length;
                }

                data = data.slice(startIndex - 1, endIndex);

                var dataSource = {
                    page: pageIndex,
                    pages: totalPages,
                    count: totalItems,
                    start: startIndex,
                    end: endIndex,
                    columns: columns,
                    items: data
                };

                callback(resp, dataSource);
                var statusColumnSuccess = $(".macAddressColumn span.success");
                var statusColumnWarning = $(".macAddressColumn span.warning");
                var statusColumnDanger = $(".macAddressColumn span.danger");

                $(statusColumnSuccess).closest("tr").addClass("hg-systems-success")
                $(statusColumnWarning).closest("tr").addClass("hg-systems-warning")
                $(statusColumnDanger).closest("tr").addClass("hg-systems-danger")

            }
        ).
            fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.error(
                    "The following error occured: " +
                        textStatus, errorThrown
                );
            });

    };
    $('#myRepeater').repeater({dataSource: getCheckinData});
```

and here's the HTML markup:

```
    <div class="fuelux">
<div class="repeater" id="myRepeater">
<div class="repeater-header">
    <div class="repeater-header-left">
        <div class="repeater-search">
            <div class="search input-group">
                <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="fueluxSearchBox"/>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="searchButton">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
              </button>
                 <button id="enableEdit" class="btn btn-success">Enable Edit</button>
            </span>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="repeater-header-right">
        <div class="btn-group selectlist repeater-filters" data-resize="auto">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="selected-label">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="caret"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Filters</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li data-value="all" data-selected="true"><a href="#">All</a></li>
                <li data-value="notRegistered"><a href="#">Not Registered</a></li>
                <li data-value="nodeIssues"><a href="#">Node Issues</a></li>
                <li data-value="checkinIssues"><a href="#">Checkin Issues</a></li>
                <li data-value="oldSoftware"><a href="#">Old Software</a></li>
            </ul>
            <input class="hidden hidden-field" name="filterSelection" readonly="readonly" aria-hidden="true"
                   type="text"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="repeater-viewport">
    <div class="repeater-canvas"></div>
    <div class="loader repeater-loader"></div>
</div>
<div class="repeater-footer">
<div class="repeater-footer-left">
    <div class="repeater-itemization">
        <span><span class="repeater-start"></span> - <span class="repeater-end"></span> of <span
                class="repeater-count"></span> items</span>

        <div class="btn-group selectlist" data-resize="auto">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="selected-label">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="caret"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li data-value="5"><a href="#">5</a></li>
                <li data-value="10" data-selected="true"><a href="#">10</a></li>
                <li data-value="20"><a href="#">20</a></li>
                <li data-value="50" data-foo="bar" data-fizz="buzz"><a href="#">50</a></li>
                <li data-value="100"><a href="#">100</a></li>
            </ul>
            <input class="hidden hidden-field" name="itemsPerPage" readonly="readonly" aria-hidden="true" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <span>Per Page</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="repeater-footer-right">
    <div class="repeater-pagination">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm repeater-prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous Page</span>
        </button>
        <label class="page-label" id="myPageLabel">Page</label>

        <div class="repeater-primaryPaging active">
            <div class="input-group input-append dropdown combobox">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-labelledby="myPageLabel">

                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"></ul>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control repeater-secondaryPaging" aria-labelledby="myPageLabel">
        <span>of <span class="repeater-pages"></span></span>


        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm repeater-next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>


            <span class="sr-only">Next Page</span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set up paging in your datasource, so that you only give the repeater the items that should be on one page. The data sent to the callback in your data source should only be the current data being viewed, then if your options available within datasource say it's the second page, change your data to the second page's data.

Treat datasource like a filter.

Comment: Have you got any examples that i can check?